# Parameterize behave feature, pytest-style

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

I'm looking run behave feature tests repeatedly, but each one with different parameters, a bit like pytest's parameterize https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-ref

I'm unable to find anything that suggests this can be done within a single run of behave. Does this have to be done externally, e.g. via a bash script, which calls behave multiple times, with each run having parameters passed in using, for example, userdata http://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/behave.html?highlight=userdata#cmdoption-define , or is there an alternative?

The actual parameters are themselves found dynamically at runtime as well, running all tests over a set of dynamically-determined parameter sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much all of the Gherkin-syntax BDD tools like Behave, Cucumber etc. support a thing called "Scenario Outline" which should do what you want. [From these examples here:](https://jenisys.github.io/behave.example/tutorials/tutorial04.html)

```
Feature: Scenario Outline (tutorial04)

  Scenario Outline: Use Blender with <thing>
    Given I put "<thing>" in a blender
    When I switch the blender on
    Then it should transform into "<other thing>"

    Examples: Amphibians
        | thing         | other thing |
        | Red Tree Frog | mush        |
        | apples        | apple juice |

    Examples: Consumer Electronics
        | thing         | other thing |
        | iPhone        | toxic waste |
        | Galaxy Nexus  | toxic waste |
```

And to implement the steps:

```
@given('I put "{thing}" in a blender')
def step_given_put_thing_into_blender(context, thing):
    context.blender = Blender()
    context.blender.add(thing)
```

Pretty simple!

Comment: Ah this is good... one thing I realise that I omitted from the original question though, the parameters are dynamically determined at runtime. Can this method support that? Can the feature/scenario be dynamically generated somehow?

Comment: Can you give me an example of one of these parameters?

Comment: The requested feature would also be helpful when you want one step to generate the multiple-valued fixture. This way, you don't need to rewrite and maintain all of the parameters as examples for each test that wants to use them.